# Collect cards of largest total value when kept in a line (extraction only from the corners)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider the following game.

A dealer produces a sequence s1 ...sn of cards, face up, where
each card si has a value vi. Then two players take turns picking a card from the sequence, but
can only pick the rst or the last card of the (remaining) sequence. The goal is to collect cards of
largest total value. (For example, you can think of the cards as bills of different denominations.)

Give an O(n^2) algorithm to compute an optimal strategy for the first player(Just the maximum obtainable code).

I have tried solving it legthwise and possible solved it here is my code...
The  array cards has the values of each card.. The 0 th element of the cards is unused and waste(Base indexing 1)!

```
  #include<bits/stdc++.h>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
   int cards[]={0,2,100,101,1};
   int n=4;
   int i,j,l,sum=204;
   int dp[n+1][n+1];
   memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      dp[i][i]=cards[i];
   for(l=2;l<=n;l++)
   {
      for(i=1;i<=n-l+1;i++)
              {
                  j=i+l-1;
                  dp[i][j]=max(cards[i]-dp[i+1][j],cards[j]-dp[i][j-1]);
               }
    }
    printf("%d\n",(sum+dp[1][n])/2);

    return 0;
    }
```

In the last print statement I have printed (sum+dp[1][n])/2 just because as the elements are 2n, n will be included and the rest n will be subtracted when I do this operation, I get the sum of included values.

Although, it gives the correct answer, I am still unable to say what does exactly dp[i][j] stands for !! It does not stand for maximum obtainable Value(as it wont give me that value directly).
So what does it denote is my another question??

Is there any other line of thinking to solve such a problem?

Comment: This sounds like the perfect use for a deque allowing you to push/pop the first or last value. I wouldn't use a fixed size array for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you have posted, `dp[i][j]` stands for the maximal difference in points that first and second player can achieve starting from a substring `i..j`: `dp[i][j]=max(first[i][j]-second[i][j])` (this is not a programming-language formula, but just to give the idea), here we call first player the one who starts from that position.

So consider a substring `i..j`. The first player (A) can choose whether he takes the first or the last card. If he takes the first card, he will get `cards[i]`, but then his opponent (B) will start from substring `i+1..j`. He will do his best and get the difference `dp[i+1][j]` in *his* favor, that is, the difference will be `pointsB - pointsA = dp[i+1][j]`. But for our position `i,j` we are interested in the difference `pointsA-pointsB`, so we take `-dp[i+1][j]` and remember the `card[i]` taken, hence

```
dp[i][j]=card[i]-dp[i+1][j]
```

There is also another variant, that is to take the last card, giving the result as

```
dp[i][j]=card[j]-dp[i][j+1]
```

Obviously, the player will choose the best option, hence you should take the maximum of two values.

Comment: Things are a lot clearer now. Can we solve it in any another way?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, one more (though very similar) approach that I see is to keep `dp[i][j]` the maximal sum that the first can get. Then we need to precalculate the sums on all substrings and the DP formula will be something like `dp[i][j]=max(card[i]+sum[i+1][j]-dp[i+1][j], ...)`.